# Which YUV format is this? Really YUV420SP?

Tags: c++, video, rgb, yuv

Below is te RGB output of a supposed YUV420SP buffer. No conversion, I' m just displaying the YUV420SP as if it were RGB, just to see some patterns.

The image is in a single `unsigned char*` buffer of size `width*height*3`. So if this is indeed YUV420SP, then I should have the Y as a black and white image, and then UV interleaved. I think I should see the Y as a black and white image, but why it repeats 3 times in my image? And should I see anything in the UV part?

Of course I tried to convert this buffer to RGB. I used https://github.com/andrechen/yuv2rgb/blob/master/yuv2rgb.h#L70 but I only get a completely black image.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your code that converts the buffer to RGB?  What format did you allocate the RGB screen? And how your are dumping the YUV bytes into the RGB buffer?

Comment: Can you please post the buffer as Grayscale image (not as a screenshot)? I suppose the dimensions of the Grayscale should be width x height*1.5.

Comment: At least post the expected resolution of the image...

Comment: @selbie here' s the code: https://github.com/andrechen/yuv2rgb/blob/master/yuv2rgb.cpp#L111, I'm gonna provide a buffer

Comment: @LucasZanella - what I meant was the code where  your dump the YUV bytes directly into the renderer.  Or at least share out the original YUV file itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format looks like [**I420** format](https://wiki.videolan.org/YUV) (also called **YV12**).

I420 is YUV 4:2:0 format with fully planar ordered format.
In YUV420, the Y color channel is the Luma (brightness) of each pixel.
U and V are the Chroma (color) channels.
The resolution of U and V is half of Y in both axes (downsampled by a factor of 0.5 in each axis).

**I420 illustration:**

Assume `unsigned char* src` is a pointer to the frame buffer, and the resolution is 640x480:

```
src ->               YYYYYY  
                     YYYYYY  
                     YYYYYY  
                     YYYYYY  
src + 640*480     -> UUU  
                     UUU  
src + (320*240)*5 -> VVV  
                     VVV
```

I used MATLAB code for restoring the RGB image from the image you have posted.

Here is the result:
[image]

---

MATLAB code (just for reference):

```matlab
I = imread('Test.png');
R = I(:,:,1);G = I(:,:,2);B = I(:,:,3);

T = zeros(size(R,1), size(R,2)*3, 'uint8');
T(:, 1:3:end) = R;T(:, 2:3:end) = G;T(:, 3:3:end) = B;
T = T';T = T(:);

Y = T(1:640*480);
U = T(640*480+1:640*480+640*480/4);
V = T(640*480+640*480/4+1:640*480+(640*480/4)*2);

Y = (reshape(Y, [640, 480]))';
U = (reshape(U, [320, 240]))';
V = (reshape(V, [320, 240]))';

U = imresize(U, 2);
V = imresize(V, 2);
YUV = cat(3, Y, U, V);
RGB = ycbcr2rgb(YUV);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done a few YUV renderers before.

A YUV 420 buffer should contain `width*height` bytes for Y, followed by `(width*height)/4)` bytes for U.  And another `(width*height)/4)` bytes for V.  Hence, if your YUV byte buffer should contain `(width*height*3)/2` bytes in size.

Just to see the grey scale pattern as you describe it, you'd need to convert the "Y" bytes into 24-bit RGB like the following:

Something like this:

```
unsigned char* YUV_BYTES = < some buffer of size (width*height*3)/2 with bytes copied in>
unsigned char* RGB_BYTES = < some buffer of size width*height*3 >

const unsigned char* dst = RGB_BYTES;
for (unsigned int r = 0; r < height; r++)
{
    unsigned int row_offset = r*width;
    for (unsigned int c = 0; c < width; c++)
    {
        *dst[0] = YUV[row_offset + c];  // R
        *dst[1] = YUV[row_offset + c];  // G
        *dst[2] = YUV[row_offset + c];  // B
        dst += 3;
    }
}
```

I think there's also an implicit assumption about the width and height of YUV images always being divisible by 4.   Your renderer might draw this image upside down depending on your graphics library and platform.